# Converting Entity Framework to ADO.NET

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

I've been working through https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-mvc-app/ and after getting the tutorial working, I'd like to convert some of the Entity Framework calls to ADO.NET.

I choose the following function:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var movie = await _context.Movie.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
        if (movie == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(movie);
    }
```

I've looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090(v=vs.110).aspx and while it makes sense, how can I return the results of the movie table to that movie object that entity does?

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple steps you need to consider. ADO works with datasets so you fire a sql statement like :

```
SELECT * FROM Movie where ID = @id
```

this gives you the data in a dataset with 1 row. Then you need to convert that row into an object so you'll need a mapping in between.

If you want to simplify your life you can use a simple ORM like Dapper which allows you to fire the request and then maps the result into an object for you, provided that the fields match.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. How could you convert it to an object?